# Making one field required when other fields are empty

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I have some fields (WP ACF) on my website and I need one field required (field_5c66e017f8359) when the others are not empty.

Who can help me with the following piece of code?

```
add_filter('acf/validate_value/key=field_5c66e017f8359', 'custom_validate_title', 20, 4);
function custom_validate_title($valid, $value, $field, $input) {
  if (!empty($_POST['acf']['field_5c6d43781bcb1']) ||
  !empty($_POST['acf']['field_5c66e094f835a']) ||
  !empty($_POST['acf']['field_5c66e0d4f835b']) ||
  !empty($_POST['acf']['field_5c66e130f835c']) ||
  !empty($_POST['acf']['field_5c703c1fd5851'])) {
  if (empty($value)) {
  $valid = 'This field is required because you have added a value to some other field';
    }
  }
  return $valid;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a logic implication : if you want the field b only required when a is not empty, you have the implication a => b. This translates to !a or b.
So in PHP this would give :

```
//if (a => b)
if (!(!empty(a)) || (!empty(b)))
```

Which can be simplified to

```
if (empty(a) || !empty(b))
```

This work also if you have to ensure that multiples fields are not empty, for instance if we want c to be required only if a OR b is not empty :

```
// (a or b) => c
if (!(!empty(a) || !empty(b)) || !empty(c))
//Equivalent to
if ((empty(a) && empty(b)) || !empty(c))
```

You will need to put parentheses around it if you put others conditions, because of operator precedence.